# Understanding input and output in ASM

Tags: linux, assembly

can Anyone please help me understand what exactly is happening here?
I am new to assembly language and have written a simple code as follows:
(I am developing on LINUX)

What i want to do is accept an integer from the user and just display what the user has entered.

```
 .section .data

number:
    .long 0

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:

movl $3, %eax           #Read system call
movl $0, %ebx                   #file descriptor (STDIN)
movl $number, %ecx              #the address to which data is to be read into.  
movl $4, %edx                   #number of bytes to be read 
int $0x80

#the entered number is stored in %ebx. it can be viewed using "echo $? "
movl number , %ebx              
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

but I am not getting the expected result. instead i am getting ASCII codes for any character that i am inputting.

for ex:

```
input - 2
output - 50

input - 1
output - 49 

input - a
output - 97 ....  and so on?
```

what is wrong? what changes should i make to have the desired result? what is the basic concept that i missed understanding.

Comment: You're reading a character from stdin and "writing" by doing an `exit()` with the character as the exit return code.  This prints the numeric value of the exit return code on the console.  What don't you understand?

Comment: ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I have figured out an answer for my own question. It may be useful for others who have just started to learn ASM and come up with same interpreting problem that i had.

first of all lets look at what is happening in the code:

```
.section .data

number:
 .long 0

.section .text

.globl _start

 _start:

   movl $3, %eax           #Read system call
   movl $0, %ebx                   #file descriptor (STDIN)
   movl $number, %ecx              #the address to which data is to be read into.  
   movl $4, %edx                   #number of bytes to be read 
   int $0x80
```

Till here what is happening is : program waits for the user to enter a number.
But , what actually is being read is the ASCII code for the "bytes".

```
Thus when a user enters '2' what actually is read is 0x32 or (110010 in binary or 
its decimal equivalent is 50)
```

The keyboard driver arranges to put these bits in a special memory location that is written when something is read from the input.
What is true for the input is same for output. When a memory location contains a binary sequence that is reported on the screen , similar ASCII conversion is applied.

(considering only ASCII standard for the moment)
    thus,
       INPUT------> ASCII CONVERSION--------> converted data (bytes)
       STORED BYTES-------->ASCII CONVERSION--------->Output Data

so , now the question arises why the output (actually the contents of %ebx ) of this program 
are not as expected...?

In our program, we are not displaying anything to screen. All echo $? is doing is simply reading whatever there is in ebx -- that is 110010 (50). If you want echo $? to display 2, then you have got to put 2 (i.e. 00010) in ebx.

The echo $? program is "interpreting" the contents of the memory (ebx) as an integer, not a character.

This is what that makes the difference!

And other thing that has to do is with the "little endian" intel architecture.
when you enter 4523 , why do we get output as "52" and not 53, 50 etc?....
    In little endian architecture , when you enter the number 4523, '4' is read
    and is stored in least significant byte in the address 'number'

If you compile/run program on big endian you may have different results (vice-versa)
And the most important thing is : when you "echo $?"  the least significant byte of %ebx 
is interpreted.

```
That is why we get output 52 i.e '4'.
```

This is a tricky and difficult concept to understand and explain. You have to spend some time thinking over this. Once you get it, you feel great.

thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Input is done in the system's native codepage. If you want to convert the numeral's ASCII code into its corresponding number then you need to do two things first:

1. Bounds check it. The value must be between '0' and '9' inclusive, otherwise it wasn't a numeral.
2. Subtract '0'. This way '0' becomes 0, '5' becomes 5, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Write it in C then use your compiler to generate the assembly.

Then fix up the assembly to make it look like you wrote it.